# How to get default height of mediacontroller?

Tags: android, mediacontroller

I was wondering if there was anyway to get what the height of the mediacontroller? Also, I need to be able to get it for both horizontal and vertical orientations.

Also, preferably I would be able to get this info in the constructor (i.e. the onCreate() method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int height = mediaController.getHeight();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight()

Comment: Doesn't work in a constructor. I need the size information before the view is created. I'm not modifying the height, so I was wondering if there was anyway to get the preset height values of the mediaController.

Comment: @onit no it's not possible to get the height before it's actually created.